# Get element from for loop in Django template for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop

I am doing a to-do app on Django with a progress circle. I need to get the percentage from for loop in Django Template by using getElementById, however, it only takes the first element in the for loop.
This is my code:

```
<div class="todo-list">
        {% for goal in goals %}
            <div class="item-row">
                {% if goal.complete == True %}
                    <strike>{{ goal }}, {{ goal.due | timeuntil }}</strike>
                {% else %}
                    <span>{{ goal }}</span>
                    <span style="float: right;" class="timer"><b>Due: </b>{{ goal.due | timeuntil }}</span>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="percent">
                            <svg>
                                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" class="track"></circle>
                                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" class="progress"></circle>
                            </svg>
                            <div class="number">
                                {% load templatetag %}
                                <h2 id="due">{{ goal|convert_to_seconds }}<span>%</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light" href="{% url 'update_goal' goal.id %}">Update</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_goal' goal.id %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

And the script part:

```
var percentage = parseInt(document.getElementById("due").innerText);
let progressCircle = document.querySelector(".progress");
progressCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = 620 - (620 * percentage) / 100;
```

I tried to use forloop.counter but it did not work. Could you help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ids must be unique in the document, so you shouldn't repeat the exact same ID each time in a loop. Use a class instead.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Even I changed it to class, it only takes the value of the first element in the loop.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it". You can't use `getElementById` on a class. You can use `querySelector` (as you currently do for the `progress` class) but that will only give you the first element - you want `querySelectorAll` to get them all, then you can loop through them to do whatever you need.

Comment: your document.getElementById("due").innerText will return XXX<span>%</span>. with XX the percentage. right ?

Comment: @EricMartin No, it only returns the number without %

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you, I solved my problem by loop them in js.